# How does Graph Api > Search Posts work?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

I have a couple of questions regarding the Graph Api > Search Posts functionality (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/):

1. What operators does the QUERY paramater accept? Usually search engines accept AND, OR, exact match ("red apples") and NOT/exclusion. I'm confused about how these operators function for Facebook.
2. What exactly does it search through? Sometimes I see results that don't match the search query at all. Does it search through the posts's message, or through comments from posts as well?

Comment: AFIK, there are no operators in the query parameter. It searches for a literal text string, and the algorithm is biased toward matching names and whole words. What it searches through is a mystery. In my experience, it examines multiple columns, and seems to include ones that are not visible to and/or requested by your app. Columns with shorter strings seem to rank higher in the algorithm than columns with longer strings, so a `name` match ranks higher than `message` match.

Answer (score 0):

The query parameter only accepts strings and not operators. You should specify a `type` too so you can filter between users, posts, etc. Depends in what you want to search for, you will need a valid user access_token.

If you are searching for posts, it will only search within the post itself, and not the comments.